# Why can't I set the last node of a LinkedList as null?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

My removeLast method are meant to return the last element in the linked list, and then return it. This is what I have so far:

```
public int removeLast() {
    int x = getLast();
    removeLast(first);
    return x;
}

private void removeLast(Node n) {
    if (n == null) {
        throw new ListException("Empty list");
    } else {
        if (n.next == null) {
            n = null;
        } else {
            removeLast(n.next);
        }
    }
}
```

first = an instance variabel in the LinkedList-class

removeLast() successfully returns the last number (well getLast() does it really, and then removeLast(Node n) is supposed to actually remove it. However, that part doesn't work.

Comment: Java is pass by value. By doing `n=null` you are just setting the parameter `n` to `null`. But this wont affect `n.next` from the caller

Comment: Also seeing how the actual `LinkedList` class implements this may help understanding linked lists: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.remove%28java.util.LinkedList.Entry%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly setting the last node of the linked list as `null`. As [@Kevin Esche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799530/kevin-esche) said,
`n = null` sets `n` as null and not the node of the linked list. In my code, I refer to the node with the `link` reference and set it to `null`.

This should work.

```
public int removeLast(Node n){  //returns and removes the last node

    int x = getLast();
    if(n == start && n.link == null) //list has only last node
        start = null;
    else {
        if(n.link.link == null)
            n.link = null;
        else
            x = removeLast(n.link);
    }
    return x;
}
```

While calling the `removeLast()` method from somewhere, pass `start` or `first` as the argument.

### Calling `removeLast()` from `main()`

Here's an example of calling the `removeLast()` method from the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
    /* add the nodes */
    System.out.println("The original LinkedList is");
    /* display the LinkedList */
    System.out.println("The last node is "+ll.removeLast(ll.start));
    System.out.println("After removing the last node, LinkedList is");
    /* display the current LinkedList */
}
```